# Deleted files on external drive (exFAT) don't go to Trash

Tags: macos, external-disk, trash, exfat

I have a Samsung T7 SSD formatted in exFAT as additional storage for my M1 Mac Mini (currently on Monterey), it's basically where I store all files that are not applications. Recently I discovered that deleting a file on this drive does not actually send that file to the Trash, it simply gets deleted immediately, with no way of recovering it other than Cmd+Z. I have checked the permissions for the Trash folder, and they seem to be in order (deleting from my Desktop, for example, works correctly), so I am wondering if the problem is the exFAT formatting, or is there another issue?

To be clear: I am trying to make any files I delete on this drive to go the Trash and be recoverable.

If possible, I would like to keep this drive in exFAT as it is removable and makes it really convenient to move files around to Windows computers when I need to. I don't want to be locked into MacOS with this drive unless it's absolutely necessary to use the trash.

Comment: what happens when you drag a file from the T7 into the trash can in the dock?

Comment: addendum: if you delete files e.g. via the terminal, they won’t be moved to the trash can but will be deleted. That’s “the way” for quite sometime - how do you “delete” files on your external drive(s)?

Comment: @slartibartfast The file gets removed from the T7, but it doesn't appear in the Trash. Same if I drag it to an open Trash window or if I right-click delete it.

Comment: add: @slartibartfast Ohh okay, I don't delete via terminal, just normally. The most common way I delete files is through cmd+backspace, which results in the same.

Comment: The behaviour is related to the file systems on the T7. If possible you should consider reformating the T7 using APFS. This will allow you to restore files from the trash.

Comment: If I create a disk image with exFat format, I can copy files to it, delete them, the files go into the .Trashes folder on the exFAT disk image. And I can recover from Trash. Was your T7 formatted on a Mac?  An exFAT drive is a bad way to store your Mac files -  liable file system corruption after, for example, power loss.

Comment: @Gilby Ahh okay, I do not remember if I formatted it on a Mac or on Windows. I'll try reformatting, do you think that could help?

Comment: @flopezablah I don't know if it will help, but reformatting on Mac removes one potential cause.